Why Random effects and Fixed effects produce the same results?
I have conducted an experiment with 40 participants and 16 treatment combinations (balanced data with 640 data points). The 16 treatment combinations are based on 5 binary variables (the main effects of my study).
As I have repeated measurements of the same individual, I have chosen a fixed-effects regression model.
As I also want to include participant-specific control variables (e.g., work experience, age) in the analysis, I have specifically chosen the "Random effects model". Results of the Hausman tests: p-value < 0.01.
Question 1:
The Random effects and fixed effects models produce the exact same results for the slopes and t-stats. Only the intercept, individual effects and the $R^2$ is (slightly) different. Is it normal that random effects and fixed effects only change the individual effects and have no effect on the slopes?
Code:
Fixed effects (Python: PanelOLS from linearmodels.panel):
mod = PanelOLS(y, X, entity_effects=True, time_effects=False)
results = mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)
Random effects(Python: RandomEffects from linearmodels.panel):
mod = RandomEffects(y, X)
results = mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)
Question 2:
When I now add my control variables (6 participant-specific variables) to the random effects model, it again has no effect on the slopes of the main effects. Only the intercept and the individual effects are different. Same question: Is it normal that random effects with and without control variables produce the same slopes of the main effect?
Many thanks for supporting on this topic!
Edit


What about the standard errors - are they identical too ? It would be a good idea to edit your post and include the summary output from the models.

For those of us who don't use Python, please also edit the question to explain, in the first model, what entity_effects=True means in the call to PanelOLS() and what the cov_type='clustered' and cluster_entity=True arguments accomplish in the subsequent call to mod.fit(). I suspect that those might be equivalent to generalized least squares (a marginal model), which with a balanced data set might be expected to give something very similar to a (conditional) mixed model.

The FE and RE coefficients would be exactly the same if you (or the package) centered each of the predictors around their respective cluster means.

Just to be sure: are they really exactly the same, or just up to the digits reported? E.g., the coefficient of A seems to differ in the 4th digit.

Without access to the data and enough time to investigate in detail, the following are just some observations/suggestions about what may be going on here.
There are two questions:


Why do the Random Effects and Fixed Effects models produce the same slopes and t-stats?



The argument entity_effects=True in PanelOLS() is telling the software to include individual-specific effects. This effectively subtracts out the within-group means of the variables (demeaning), removing between-group variation.
By using cov_type='clustered' and cluster_entity=True, you are accounting for possible correlations within entities by adjusting the standard errors using a clustered covariance matrix. This does not change the estimated coefficients but adjusts the standard errors to account for intra-cluster correlations, which may explain why the t-statistics, which are based on those adjusted standard errors, are the same between models.
In balanced panel data (as in your case), fixed effects and random effects can give very similar (or identical) slope estimates. This occurs because, with balanced data, the variation between and within entities is more similar. The Hausman test result (p < 0.01) suggests that the fixed effects model is preferred, but the random effects model can still provide unbiased estimates under these conditions.



Why do control variables have no effect on the slopes of the main effects in the random effects model?


Again, some possibilities are:

If the participant-specific control variables are not correlated with the main effects, then including them in the model will primarily affect the intercept and not the slopes. The control variables adjust for individual-specific characteristics, but if these do not interact with or correlate with the main effects, they won’t impact the slopes of the main variables.
With balanced data and when the control variables primarily capture between-participant differences, the within-participant variation remains unaffected. Thus, the slopes of the main effects would not be expected to change much.

Of course, a lot of the above would be explained if the experiment was randomised.
